# Android Tabbar: why activities are recreated each time I switch tab?

Tags: android, tabbar

I have 2 projects with tabbars. In each project activities are binded to tabbars. However, in the first one activities are created only for the first time I switch to certain tab (I suppose this behaviour is normal). In the second one onCreate is called each time I switch to a tab regardless the fact whether instance of this activity was created before.

I cant understand why 2 apps (2 projects = 2 apps) behave in such a different way. In neither project I tried to archieve any behaviour - it happened by itself. Can anyone explain me possible reasons of different behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code we can only guess.

Perhaps you are calling `finish()` on your activities in the one app and not in the other.